# Display author avatar in posts/homepage after wordpress magento integration

Tags: wordpress, magento

I am using FishPig extension to integrate wordpress in magento everything is ok.. now i want to display author gravatar in every post & also on homepage a small author image under title of every post. here is blog url - www.postmygreetings.com/blog/

Edit:

I am using this code to display author name, post date and tags under every post on homepage now i also want to display small author image:

```
<?php echo stripslashes($this->__('This entry was posted in %s and tagged %s on %s<span class=\"by-author\"> by %s</span>.', 
         $this->getCategoryString($post), 
         $this->getTagString($post), 
         $post->getPostDate(), 
         $post->getAuthor()->getDisplayName())
  ) ?>
```

Comment: can you share the code where you want the gravatar to be displayed? please include in it the code that you use to get post title, getting the authors image is similar

Comment: I am using this code to display author name, post date and tags under every post on homepage now i also want to display small author image `<?php echo stripslashes($this->__('This entry was posted in %s and tagged %s on %s<span class=\"by-author\"> by %s</span>.', $this->getCategoryString($post), $this->getTagString($post), $post->getPostDate(), $post->getAuthor()->getDisplayName())) ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the users avatar you'll have to create a function similar to wordpress [`get_avatar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) you can find it's [code here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1588).

After you have this function just call it with the correct argumets and it should work...

You get the argumets from objects that you can already use like

> $post->getAuthor()->getDisplayName())

Comment: Do you know where to add new fuctions after wordpress-magento integration because default funvtions.php file in wp folder doesn't work?

Comment: @SatinderSingh I don't know exactly but check what function gives values to $post variable check where it is and see if you can place your custom function there (and if it's the right place...)